# How can I run javascript code with limited function access

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to load a javascript file as a script for a specific task and it should only able to accessible​ by a specific function that I defined.

I don't want people who write the code to access global objects like `process` or some global function.

I only want users to use functions or objects that I prepare for them, and it should allow them to define their own functions and variables, others are not allowed.

Is there some package that could do it?

for example:

```
process; // should be undefined
getProcessInfo(); // the function that I prepared for them

var process = 0; // should be ok
```